# Password while starting hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My system is asking password whenever I am starting Hadoop cluster.

I have added the key in .ssh folder.

**start-dfs.sh**

> 19/01/22 20:38:56 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable Starting namenodes on [localhost] XXXX@localhost's
>   password:  localhost: starting namenode, logging to
>   /XXX/XXX/XXX/XX/XXX.out XXXX@localhost's password:

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved. I was missing one important step after ssh-keygen command.
I executed 'ssh-copy-id username@remote_host' and issue got resolved.